# How to join two files based on one column in AWK (using wildcards)

Tags: awk

I have 2 files, and I need to compare column 2 from file 2 with column 3 from file 1.

File 1

```
"testserver1","testserver1.domain.net","-1.1.1.1-10.10.10.10-"
"testserver2","testserver2.domain.net","-2.2.2.2-20.20.20.20-200.200.200.200-"
"testserver3","testserver3.domain.net","-3.3.3.3-"
```

File 2

```
"windows","10.10.10.10","datacenter1"
"linux","2.2.2.2","datacenter2"
"aix","4.4.4.4","datacenter2"
```

Expected Output

```
"testserver1","testserver1.domain.net","windows","10.10.10.10","datacenter1"
"testserver2","testserver2.domain.net","linux","2.2.2.2","datacenter2"
```

All I have been able to find statements that only work if the columns are identical, I need it to work if column 3 from file 1 **contains** value from column 2 from file 2

I've tried this, but again, it only works if the columns are identical (which I don't want):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","};NR == FNR{f[$3] = $1","$2;next};$2 in f {print f[$2],$0}' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Comment: What have you tried? You've tagged your question [tag:awk], but I don't see any awk code in your question. Hard to help you debug code that you haven't shared.

Comment: What should the output be if file1 contained `"testserver1","testserver1.domain.net","-2.2.2.2-10.10.10.10-"` or any other case where one line of file1 matches multiple lines of file2?

Comment: Such an occurrence would not exist with my dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hacky!

```
$ awk -F'","' 'NR==FNR {n=split($NF,x,"-"); for(i=2;i<n;i++) a[x[i]]=$1 FS $2; next} 
               $2 in a {print a[$2] "\"," $0}' file1 file2

"testserver1","testserver1.domain.net","windows","10.10.10.10","datacenter1"
"testserver2","testserver2.domain.net","linux","2.2.2.2","datacenter2"
```

assumes the lookup is unique, i.e. file1 records are mutually exclusive in that field.